DOMException when trying to send data to a IFrame in dart
i was trying to create an iframe using dart web and pass some data to the iframe, using the following extension i found on https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/54443 which was specifically made as a workaround to this problem
extension on HTMLIFrameElement {
  void safelyPostMessage(
    JSAny? message,
    String optionsOrTargetOrigin,
  ) {
    (this as JSObject)
        .getProperty<JSObject>('contentWindow'.toJS)
        .callMethod('postMessage'.toJS, message, optionsOrTargetOrigin.toJS);
  }
}

called the code as follows:
Future<void> sendMessage(String command, Map<String, Object?> params) {
    final message = {
      'command': command,
      ...params,
    }.jsify();
    _frame.safelyPostMessage(message, '*');
    return Future.value();
  }

but this still results in the same browser error as the issue saying
DOMException: Failed to read a named property 'toString' from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "localhost:55478" from accessing a cross-origin frame. 
I took the code from dart pad's repo at https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/blob/3a6114586339e810fcd65d2884fddf1dffc22694/pkgs/dartpad_ui/lib/execution/frame.dart#L133
I cloned the dart-pad repository and tried to run it myself but even that gives me the same error
